# ag-grid setRowHeight not working

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am stuck on this grid, I don't see the error I try every single example but it's doesn't work for me !

My problem is to set the grid fit the rows content this is my version of gridoptions

```
 this.gridOptions = {
      pagination:true,
      enableColResize: true,
      animateRows: true,    

    };
this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: "Account ID",
        field: "AccountID",
        minWidth: 100
      }, ... ]

 this.gridOptions.onGridReady = () =>
    {
      this.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
      this.setRowData();
    }
```

and when the user click on the button the grid must apply this new changes

```
resizeWind()


     {
        this.gridOptions.api.forEachNode(rowNode => {
          if (rowNode.data) {
            rowNode.setRowHeight(100);
          }
          // console.log(rowNode.data);
        });
        this.gridOptions.api.onRowHeightChanged();
      }
```

Notes 
- Angular 4 with webpack via angular-cli

Answer (score 0):

I created a [plnkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/FEK7wtQfVwUXeYjOh6PK/) with your function... everything seems to be working fine in this example. Perhaps make sure that you have the click event binded properly?

```
<button (click)="resizeWind()">click me</button>
```

Comment: Yes I have used the grid with systemjs and it was fine until I switch to webpack with angular-cli.

Comment: So now your entire grid isn't working at all? If so, you seem to have asked the wrong question...

Comment: No, the grid was shown but I can not resize the row height can u please use it with angular cli ?